# Calculating 3D Euclidean Distance without overflows or underflows

Tags: c, 3d, floating-accuracy, euclidean-distance

Calculating 3D Euclidean Distance without overflows or underflows

Hello there,

I have written code to calculate the 3D Euclidean Distance between two vectors.
I know this is a pretty common operation, however my case is a little peculiar because we need to add a scalar quantity before computing the square root.

The following is the routine in C code:

```
void calculateAdjustedDistances3D(float *Ax, float *Ay, float *Az,
                                  float *Bx, float *By, float *Bz,
                                  float scalar, float *distances, int N)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        float dx = Ax[i] - Bx[i];
        float dy = Ay[i] - By[i];
        float dz = Az[i] - Bz[i];

        float dx2 = dx * dx;
        float dy2 = dy * dy;
        float dz2 = dz * dz;

        // potential for overflow/underflow
        float adjustedSquaredDistance = dx2 + dy2 + dz2 + scalar;

        distances[i] = sqrtf(adjustedSquaredDistance);
    }
}
```

For my application the range of input values can be very small, and also very big.
Therefore I am now considering whether it would be necessary to prevent overflow and underflow in the calculation of these distances.
I am aware there are techniques to eliminate the danger of overflow/underflow at the expense of making the code a little slower.

For instance the hypot() function is generally used to solve this problem, however it cannot be used in this case due to the scalar quantity being added before computing the square root.

How could I rewrite my code in order to mitigate or ideally eliminate the possibility of overflows and underflows in the calculations?

Comment: *"very small, and also very big"*. What are the actual limits? And will those limits cause a problem? Seems like you're trying to solve a problem without first determining whether the problem exists.

Comment: There are no limits. The full range of 32-bit floating point values could _potentially_ be used. It is true that in the general case the values entered will not cause a problem, however they could. For the sake of writing robust code I am trying to protect myself against those unlikely but possible scenarios.

Comment: Declare dx,dy,dz,dx2,etc as `double` and use `sqrt` in place of `sqrtf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for positive values of `scalar`, one could perhaps interpret it as an "extra dimension" and invoke the `hypot` function in the following way

```
distances[i] = hypot(hypot(hypot(dx, dy), dz), sqrt(scalar))
```

**EDIT:**

in order to avoid invocation of the function `hypot`, one might follow the implementation of the [BLAS function `snrm2`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/df1/snrm2_8f_source.html) which is supposed to calculate vector 2-norm in a "robust" way:

```
float scale, ssq, ax;
const float x[4] = {dx, dy, dz, sqrt(scalar)};

scale = 0;
ssq = 1;

for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
    if(x[j] != 0){
        ax = fabs(x[j]);
        if(scale < ax){
            ssq = 1 + ssq*(scale/ax)*(scale/ax);
            scale = ax;
        }else{
            ssq += (ax/scale)*(ax/scale);
        }
    }
}
distances[i] = scale*sqrt(ssq);
```

Comment: Yes, this would work, however it would be extremely slow since I would have to calculate 4 square roots. I think that in order to keep running the code at a decent speed the hypot() solution should be avoided. Good thinking though...

Comment: in that case, one could perhaps take inspiration from the BLAS function `snrm2` which seems to perform some kind of scaling to mitigate floating point errors (also, it calculates only one square root) - http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/df1/snrm2_8f_source.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you.